# C++11 RValue: What critical role does it play in templates declarations

Tags: c++, c++11

It is really a confusion for me on why should I use && when I want to forward an argument, when using bind().

I know it is a literal to denote `RValues`, and I have read about `Rvalues`, their difference with old cpp values (so called `lvalues`). But is not yet clear crystal to me that why such function:

```
template<typename _Callable, typename... Args>
bool assign_threads_instructions(_Callable&& __f, Args&&... __args)
{
    for( int inc = 0; inc < global_container_size; inc++ )
    {
        global_container[inc] = std::thread(std::forward<_Callable>(__f), std::forward<Args>(__args)...);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Which is declared inside a template, works OK, but if I remove those double &&, the compiler throws an error. The error is:

```
too few arguments to function
     unused  invoke( Functor& f )                        { f(); return unused(); }
```

What critical role does `Rvalue` play here?

Comment: Do note that `T&&` is actually a forwarding reference and not necessarily a rvalue reference.

Comment: In this case it is a forwarding reference not an rvalue reference

Comment: You ask about `bind` then show code that doesn't have `bind` in it.

Comment: BTW, forwarding in a loop seems suspicious. passing by const reference seems better here.

Comment: @Jarod42 Why is it inefficient?

Comment: Not inefficient, but if you pass `std::unique_ptr`, it would be `null_ptr` after the first iteration.